# Confused by Android Kotlin Example: Creating a new object but missing necessary constructor parameters

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and trying to learn all the syntactic niceties that Kotlin has vs. Java... But I'm a little confused by the Android Kotlin example on the following page: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle

Specifically, this code snippet:

```
myLocationListener = MyLocationListener(this) { location ->
            // update UI
        }
```

where the class definition for `MyLocationListener` is as follows:

```
internal class MyLocationListener(
        private val context: Context,
        private val callback: (Location) -> Unit
) {
...
```

Questions:

1. It seems as though Kotlin understands that the code block after `MyLocationListener(this)` is meant to be the value of the `callback` parameter. Is that true? How does the compiler recognize this?
2. If #1 is correct, what would happen if `MyLocationListener` had a 3rd parameter after `callback`, say another lambda `callback2`... How would the code snippet above change? Would there be two code blocks after `MyLocationListener(this)`?

I did a little sleuthing through the basic Kotlin docs and couldn't find a name for this pattern... Coming from Java-brain I would have expected the code to be:

```
myLocationListener = MyLocationListener(this, (location) -> { })
```

Comment: This is called a "trailing lambda". Read here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas

Comment: (1) Yes, that's true. The compiler recognizes this because that's the syntax it was designed to handle. (2) Only the last parameter, assuming it's a function type, can be passed as a "trailing lambda".